# pytorch fix gpu mem leak after exactly 10 minibatches

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

So I had this problem for a few days that is driving me crazy. I have a seq2seq model (specifically a Listen, Attend and Spell model from google) that Im training and always goes crazy wild in gpu memory usage when reaching mini batch number 10. I have tried shuffling the dataloader to make sure the problem wasnt related to the specific data being retrieved in the 10th time but the error persisted to happen in this 10th iteration.

My train loop looks as follows:

```py
for epoch in range(start_epoch, epochs):
    epoch_step = 0
    train_loss = []
    train_ler = []
    batch_loss = 0
    for i, (data) in enumerate(train_loader):
        print(
            f"Current Epoch: {epoch} Loss {np.round(batch_loss, 3)} | Epoch step: {epoch_step}/{len(train_loader)}",
            end="\r",
            flush=True,
        )
        # Adjust LR
        tf_rate = tf_rate_upperbound - (tf_rate_upperbound - tf_rate_lowerbound) * min(
            (float(global_step) / tf_decay_step), 1
        )
        with torch.no_grad():
            inputs = data[1]["inputs"].cuda()
            labels = data[2]["targets"].cuda()

        # minibatch execution
        batch_loss, batch_ler = batch_iterator(
            batch_data=inputs,
            batch_label=labels,
            las_model=las,
            optimizer=optimizer,
            tf_rate=tf_rate,
            is_training=True,
            max_label_len=params["data"]["vocab_size"],
            label_smoothing=params["training"]["label_smoothing"],
        )
        del inputs
        del labels
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()

        train_loss.append(batch_loss)
        train_ler.extend(batch_ler)

        global_step += 1
        epoch_step += 1
```

Where `batch_iterator` trains the network from the minibatch. Batch_iterator looks as follows:

```py
def batch_iterator(
    batch_data,
    batch_label,
    las_model,
    optimizer,
    tf_rate,
    is_training,
    max_label_len,
    label_smoothing,
    use_gpu=True,
):
    label_smoothing = label_smoothing
    max_label_len = min([batch_label.size()[1], max_label_len])
    criterion = nn.NLLLoss(ignore_index=0).cuda()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    raw_pred_seq, _ = las_model(
        batch_data=batch_data,
        batch_label=batch_label,
        teacher_force_rate=tf_rate,
        is_training=is_training,
    )
    pred_y = (
        torch.cat([torch.unsqueeze(each_y, 1) for each_y in raw_pred_seq], 1)[:, :max_label_len, :]
    ).contiguous()

    if label_smoothing == 0.0 or not (is_training):
        pred_y = pred_y.permute(0, 2, 1)  # pred_y.contiguous().view(-1,output_class_dim)
        true_y = torch.max(batch_label, dim=2)[1][:, :max_label_len].contiguous()  # .view(-1)

        loss = criterion(pred_y, true_y)
        # variable -> numpy before sending into LER calculator
        batch_ler = LetterErrorRate(
            torch.max(pred_y.permute(0, 2, 1), dim=2)[1]
            .cpu()
            .numpy(),  # .reshape(current_batch_size,max_label_len),
            true_y.cpu().data.numpy(),
        )  # .reshape(current_batch_size,max_label_len), data)

    else:
        true_y = batch_label[:, :max_label_len, :].contiguous()
        true_y = true_y.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor) if use_gpu else true_y.type(torch.FloatTensor)
        loss = label_smoothing_loss(pred_y, true_y, label_smoothing=label_smoothing)
        batch_ler = LetterErrorRate(
            torch.max(pred_y, dim=2)[1].cpu().numpy(),  # .reshape(current_batch_size,max_label_len),
            torch.max(true_y, dim=2)[1].cpu().data.numpy(),
        )  # .reshape(current_batch_size,max_label_len), data)

    if is_training:
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

    batch_loss = loss.cpu().data.numpy()

    return batch_loss, batch_ler
```

The full code of the project is inside this github repository https://github.com/jiwidi/las-pytorch if want to check it:

While running in a v100 (16gb of gpu ram) the usage of memory is constant around 4gb and spikes to 14gb in 10th iteration. As the error persists to happen in this exact iteration regardless that I shuffle the dataloader I believe the error is in my code.

I also tried to put print statmentes before each batch_iterator where I would print the size of both `inputs` and `labels`, the size of them were equal to the ones in the previous minibatches. Output here:

```
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 0 | Epoch step: 0/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1536, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 3.7290000915527344 | Epoch step: 1/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1536, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 4.315999984741211 | Epoch step: 2/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1568, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 3.928999900817871 | Epoch step: 3/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1088, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 3.822999954223633 | Epoch step: 4/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1504, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 4.47599983215332 | Epoch step: 5/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1376, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 3.9019999504089355 | Epoch step: 6/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1248, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 4.1620001792907715 | Epoch step: 7/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1216, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 3.5490000247955322 | Epoch step: 8/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1600, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 5.377999782562256 | Epoch step: 9/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1504, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
Current Epoch: 0 Loss 4.515999794006348 | Epoch step: 10/28539
For epoch 0 inputs has size torch.Size([1, 1248, 40])mb and labels has size torch.Size([1, 177, 42])mb
```

The the actual error pytorch gives me:

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 138, in <module>
    label_smoothing=params["training"]["label_smoothing"],
  File "/home/fhjaime966/las-pytorch/solver/solver.py", line 63, in batch_iterator
    is_training=is_training,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fhjaime966/las-pytorch/model/las_model.py", line 34, in forward
    listener_feature, ground_truth=batch_label, teacher_force_rate=teacher_force_rate
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fhjaime966/las-pytorch/model/las_model.py", line 212, in forward
    rnn_input, hidden_state, listener_feature
  File "/home/fhjaime966/las-pytorch/model/las_model.py", line 180, in forward_step
    attention_score, context = self.attention(rnn_output, listener_feature)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fhjaime966/las-pytorch/model/las_model.py", line 296, in forward
    * attention_score[0].unsqueeze(2).repeat(1, 1, listener_feature.size(2)),
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 12.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.75 GiB total capacity; 14.69 GiB already allocated; 6.88 MiB free; 14.69 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

I know this is quite a big problem to debug as you would need to check the code at the repository https://github.com/jiwidi/las-pytorch to get an understanding of what is running so any help or tips with debugging gpu mem usage in pytorch are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you verify whether the 10th batch is using teacher forcing and consequently what the value of `max_steps` is in [`Speller.forward`](https://github.com/jiwidi/las-pytorch/blob/24efb4a955ceea737baa8cc073598f77ec4e926b/model/las_model.py#L210)?  Judging from your [configs](https://github.com/jiwidi/las-pytorch/blob/24efb4a955ceea737baa8cc073598f77ec4e926b/config/common_voice-config.yaml#L34) the `max_step` is 2463, which is a lot bigger than the 177 from the ground truths.

Comment: One thing I've done in the past is call .backward() after each sample instead of after each minibatch.  This will compute the gradients, but not apply them.  You can still call optimizer.step() after a minibatch worth of samples.  Doesn't get to the root of your current issue though.

Comment: @MichaelJungo you were right on point! Max steps is 2463 exactly at 10th iteration  as it comes from the teacher randomly expanding (I had a custom seed so even shuffling the dataloader wouldnt fix this). I had actually figure out the max length of my sequences is at max 700 and even if the spike still happens it is for a reason and is controlled now. I also had a bug were the first 100 sentences being drawn had the same target sequence but that has been fixed in the data preprocess. Will continue working on this to optimize it! Please answer the question so i can give you reward.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code in your repository, I think you can solve your problem by embedding your training in a function. If Cuda overloads, it means that you have too many variables accessible at this moment.

Overall I think it is bad practice to use 'del' to delete parameters within the loop, to save memory space. You should consider using function scoping. See here : https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cuda-run-out-of-memory/49412/3

(Especially ptrblck's answer).

Hope this little tip helps.

Comment: would wrapping my train code in a `main` function do the job? and the call if the `if __name__ == "__main__":`  Will try it and get back with some results. Thanks for checking the repository!

Answer (score 0):

You are using teacher forcing with a probability of 0.9 in `Speller.forward`. When teacher forcing is used, the maximum number of steps are limited to the sequence length of the ground truth, otherwise it's a fixed value, which is set to 2463 in the configs, for instance in [common_voice-config.yaml](https://github.com/jiwidi/las-pytorch/blob/24efb4a955ceea737baa8cc073598f77ec4e926b/config/common_voice-config.yaml#L34). The 2463 is much larger than the sequence lengths of your ground truths, hence it also uses more memory, unless it stops early. The 10th epoch is the first epoch that did not use teacher forcing, and because of having set the random seed, that remains consistent.

Setting the maximum steps to a lower number will prevent the memory usage from getting out of hand.

Besides that, you are [keeping track of the predictions and the attention of each time step](https://github.com/jiwidi/las-pytorch/blob/24efb4a955ceea737baa8cc073598f77ec4e926b/model/las_model.py#L214-L215), but you are leaving them on the GPU, therefore they occupy unnecessary memory. They aren't used for any further calculations, and their use is presumably limited to having the information for each time step, for example for visualising the attention.

You should put them onto the CPU and you can also detach them from the computational graph, because they don't need to keep track of the gradients anymore:

```py
raw_pred_seq.append(raw_pred.detach().cpu())
attention_record.append(attention_score.detach().cpu())
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem: exactly every 10 epochs approximately 250 Mb added to the memory that has already been being used.
First, I searched the reason among some "torch"/"cuda" stuff, but the solution was another: saving the optimizer state dict using "deepcopy"! I wonder:)
I turned off the saving, and the problem was solved.
I have no idea how the deepcopy works in order why it loads additional GPU memory exactly every 10 epochs (no loop in my code is of 10). That's why I didn't keep it in mind first. Optimizer state dicts can be of huge weight, and in my case, it was the reason indeed.